# How to include a class by default in all nodes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, puppet

How do I include this class `all` in all nodes by default?

snippet from my manifests/nodes.pp

```
class all {

  case $operatingsystem {
    debian, ubuntu: {
      include hosts
      include ssh
    }
    default: {
      err("OS NOT supported")
    }
  }
}

node default {
  include all
}

node 'dobby' {
  include all ## << 
  include apache
  include logrotate
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 node 'dobby' inherits default  {.... }
```

will inherit all definitions from the node `default`.